# Apache, where to move files for other ports than 80 in linux

Tags: linux, apache, server, centos

Say I was using ports for versioning, and wanted to test out websites on port 8080, then publish on the default port 80.

The default location for apache server files is:
/var/www/html/

How do you specify which files are loaded through port 80 and which ones are loaded through port 8080? Is it a physical location within a directory where you have to move the files?

(all of the ports mentioned are opened and setup)

Thanks.

Comment: Look into the `VirtualHost` and `Listen` directives. For an example, look at the configuration files for a website accessed through HTTPS. Using a virtual host, you could leave it on port 80 but define a new host name.

Comment: Problem is I only have sudo access to my home user directory on the remote server, and the root apache directory is set to a virtual directory: /var/www/, so from what I gather from my one day experience with apache remote server directory structure, I need sudo access to /var/www/ or the root virtual directory needs to be set to my home user folder, where I do have sudo priveleges

Comment: If you don't have direct access to the configuration files of the server, and can only publish to the `DocumentRoot` folder, you're going to struggle. You won't be able to configure files to come via separate ports (i.e., a `VirtualHost`). The best thing to do is to use a virtual machine on your local PC/Mac (using VirtualBox), try to replicate the configuration of your remote server as closely as possible, then perform your testing on that.

Comment: I think I'll be able to get the admin to move the virtual directory root to my user directory. But the virtualbox testing idea is good for testing out the deployment of the database, so I know the exact steps once I have to sit down next to the administrator. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Just use VirtualBox for the whole dev and test cycle. It means you won't have to go around altering a live server